# passing a lua table as an argument

Tags: lua

In file1.lua I have something like

```
require "file2"
outerTable = { ["thing1"] = {"1", "2", "3"}, ["thing2"] = {"4", "5", "6"}}
penultimateThing = callAFunction(outerTable["thing1"])
```

in file2.lua I have something like

```
callAFunction(table)
    for k,v in ipairs(table) do
        print(k, v)
    end
end
```

When I try to pass a nested table like this, it's always nil. What gives?

Comment: Replace `for k,v in ipairs do` with `for k,v in ipairs(table) do`

Comment: I actually have that. I just typed it wrong in the post. I'll edit the op

Comment: are you getting an error that states something like `table expected and got nil`? or are you seeing prints that say `nil, nil`? if you are seeing an error what line is it on.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another typo, but you are not saying `function callAFunction`. Without that, I get the error: `<eof> expected near end`. This means that there is an `end` where the compiler assumes the file should end. Tracing back we find that we close a `for` loop and that we want to close the function definition. The function definition, however, is not opened, so cannot be closed either.

Try to change it to:

```
function callAFunction(table)
    for k,v in ipairs(table) do
        print(k, v)
    end
end
```

For me, this seems to work